# Express $\sinh x$ in terms of the exponential function

Tags: trigonometry

I found that $\cosh x=\frac{e^x + e^{-x}}{2}$ but I am unsure how to find $\sinh x$ in terms of the exponential function by using Euler's formula.

Comment: This gives $\cosh x$ instead of $\cos x$.

Comment: alright, I still don't know how to solve it

Comment: we have $\cosh(z)^2-\sinh(z)^2=1$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** I don't know what are your definitions of $\sinh$ and $\cosh$ but mine are:
$$
\cosh(x) + \sinh(x) = \exp (x)\\
\cosh(x) - \sinh(x) = \exp (-x)
$$
From here you can deduce the expressions of both.

NB: this means that $\cosh$ is the even part of $\exp$ and $\sinh$ is its odd part.